# Client not receiving Responses from Gateway (OpenStack)

Tags: networking, routing, gateway, openstack

I'm trying to use a Ubuntu box as the gateway for my LAN. This is my setup:

- Ubuntu Gateway

  - ens3: WAN 10.0.10.163 netmask 255.255.255.224
  - ens4: LAN 10.0.10.231 netmask 255.255.255.224
- Ubuntu Client

  - ens3: LAN 10.0.10.238 netmask 255.255.255.224

`net.ipv4.conf.ip_forward` has been enabled on the Ubuntu gateway. These are the iptables rules in place on the gateway:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o ens3 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A FORWARD -i ens4 -j ACCEPT
```

Routing table of the gateway:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.0.10.161     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 ens3
10.0.10.160     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.224 U     0      0        0 ens3
10.0.10.224     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.224 U     0      0        0 ens4
169.254.169.254 10.0.10.161     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 ens3
```

Routing table of the client:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.0.10.231     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 ens3
10.0.10.224     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.224 U     100    0        0 ens3
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 ens3
169.254.169.254 10.0.10.225     255.255.255.255 UGH   100    0        0 ens3
```

Both machines can ping each other, so there is no problem with the LAN connection between them. However, if I try to ping e.g. 8.8.8.8 from the client, it shows 100% packet loss and a tcpdump on the LAN interface shows no ping responses. Yet, if I do a tcpdump on the gateway, it shows both the echo request from the client and a echo response:

```
user@snort-id:~$ sudo tcpdump -i ens4 icmp
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on ens4, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
13:33:08.503943 IP 10.0.10.238 > google-public-dns-a.google.com: ICMP echo request, id 4424, seq 1, length 64
13:33:08.507787 IP google-public-dns-a.google.com > 10.0.10.238: ICMP echo reply, id 4424, seq 1, length 64
13:33:09.526402 IP 10.0.10.238 > google-public-dns-a.google.com: ICMP echo request, id 4424, seq 2, length 64
13:33:09.530203 IP google-public-dns-a.google.com > 10.0.10.238: ICMP echo reply, id 4424, seq 2, length 64
13:33:10.551124 IP 10.0.10.238 > google-public-dns-a.google.com: ICMP echo request, id 4424, seq 3, length 64
13:33:10.554807 IP google-public-dns-a.google.com > 10.0.10.238: ICMP echo reply, id 4424, seq 3, length 64
```

So just from the tcpdump it looks like the forwarding is working. However, the client does not receive any response. I am not sure if this is important, but both the gateway and the client are running on OpenStack.

Would really appreciate any help on this.

Edit: As requested:

Iptables output of the gateway:

```
user@snort-id:~$ sudo iptables -t nat -vnL
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 541 packets, 37916 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 9 packets, 840 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 43 packets, 33087 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 23 packets, 31668 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
  493 31309 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      ens3    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0


user@snort-id:~$ sudo iptables -vnL
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 1938 packets, 132K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 1754 packets, 238K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
 1754  110K ACCEPT     all  --  ens4   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 1250 packets, 168K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

Both `iptables -t nat -vnL` and `iptables -vnL` show no rules on the client.

Comment: Did you allow ICMP in your OpenStack console?

Comment: The client and gateway instance are both in the same security group which allows egress and ingress icmp traffic.

Comment: Could you add the output of `iptables -t nat -vnL` and `iptables -vnL` of both hosts?

Comment: Updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, seems like I was wrong about OpenStack(in my case Devstack) not causing the problem. By default, Devstack uses some anti ip and mac spoofing measures. For this, it creates iptables rules on the Devstack host which cause the response packets from the gateway to the client to be dropped. To fix this, I've added the following lines to my Devstack `local.conf`

```
Q_USE_SECGROUP=False

[[post-config|$NOVA_CONF]]
[DEFAULT]
security_group_api=nova
firewall_driver=nova.virt.firewall.NoopFirewallDriver
```

Note that this essentially disables the entire firewall.